# npm - dependency conflict - <p1> and <p2> are using different versions of moment

Tags: javascript, npm

I am using two dependencies in my project which depend on different versions of moment.

My understanding was that npm allows to use different versions of a package in dependency tree.

```
<p1>
   - moment@2.29.1
<p2>
   - moment@2.29.4
```

I thought this would work. And it does for `npm i` but when I do `npm run build` which is using `ember build` I get below error:

```
<p1> and <p2> are using different versions of moment (^2.29.1 located at <path>/node_modules/moment/moment.js vs 2.29.4 located at <path>node_modules/<p2>/node_modules/moment/moment.js)
```

Though I solved it by pinning moment@2.29.4 in my package.json but that doesn't seem correct to me as I am not using the package directly.

Why am I getting the error in first place and it there a better solution?

I am using npm 6x version.

Comment: You can try creating `.npmrc` file inside your project with the contents `legacy-peer-deps=true`, delete `node_modules` and then run `npm i` again. If this does not help - you will have to debug this deeper by starting `ember build` directly through `node --inspect-brk .....`